# How to store pdf resume files in the file system and save link in mysql in a laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf, web

I am working on a project in laravel that stores the query and informations about organisation staffs. For that, I need to store their photo and resume in pdf format. I am using `Image Intervention` package to store the photo of the staff. But Don't know how to store the pdf file in the database. So is there any packages to store the pdf into the database with laravel? Or any other way of storing in the FS and store the name or link of it into the DB?

```
I wrote a function that will store all the information in the database.
But the program throughs an error of 302. And I looked into the Intervention documentation and it says that it doesn't saves '.pdf' documents. 



public function addStaff(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'staff_name'=>['required'],
            'post'=>['required'],
            'email'=>['required'],
            'birthDate'=>['required','date'],
            'birth_Mark'=>['string'],
            'perm_address'=>['required'],
            'address'=>['required'],
            'contact'=>['required'],
            'alt_contact'=>['required'],
            'service_status'=>['required'],
            'joining_date'=>['required','date'],
            'NID'=>['required','string'],
            'passport'=>['string'],
            'resume'=>['required','string'],
            'photo'=>['required','string'],
            'gender'=>['required'],
        ]);

        // photo part starts

        if($request->resume){
            $resume = $request->file('resume');
            $resumeName = rand().".".$resume->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $resumeLocation = public_path("backend/imageStore/staff/resume/".$resumeName);
            File::make($resume)->save($resumeLocation);


            if($request->photo){
                $picture = $request->file('photo');
                $pcustomname = rand().".".$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path("backend/imageStore/staff/photo/".$pcustomname);
                Image::make($picture)->save($location);


                Staff::create([
                    'staff_name' =>$request->staff_name,
                    'post' =>$request->post,
                    'email' =>$request->email,
                    'birthDate' =>$request->birthDate,
                    'birth_Mark' =>$request->birth_Mark,
                    'perm_address' =>$request->perm_address,
                    'address' =>$request->address,
                    'contact' =>$request->contact,
                    'alt_contact' =>$request->alt_contact,
                    'service_status' =>$request->service_status,
                    'joining_date' =>$request->joining_date,
                    'NID' =>$request->NID,
                    'passport' =>$request->passport,
                    'resume' =>$resumeName,
                    'photo' =>$pcustomname,
                    'gender' =>$request->gender,
                ]);
                return back();
            }
            
        }

        // return back();
    }
```

Comment: Read about something in Laravel called 'disks'. You store the PDF file on the disk and then you make a symlink from that disk (in thr storage directory) to the public directory, where the file can be accessed. You remember the file you saved after triple checking that a file actually was created

Comment: Go piece by piece. Use the dd() function to see what you're saving is actually there. Check, check, double check. One last thing: you're validating your request, but after that, you're just saving items from that same request. You're not grabbing the information from your validated part, but from the unvalidated part. If I want an item from validated request, I'll do: `$request->validated()->field`

Comment: You can use `disks` as described in [Laravel Filestorage](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem) to save the PDFs in storage for example. Save the file name in the database, and using Storage again, you can download it like: `return Storage::download('filename.pdf');`